# Add every returned string into a text file

Tags: javascript

I have a program that returns the title of a youtube video when provided its id and it works fine. The issue is when I try to add the returned result to a text file it only adds the last string whereas when I `console.log` the result it prints the whole returned result. Where did I go wrong. How can I make it add the whole returned string into the text file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
google.youtube('v3').videos.list({
  key: youtubeKey,
  part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
  id: 'Ks-_Mh1QhMc,c0KYU2j0TM4,eIho2S0ZahI',
}).then((response) => {
const {
  data
} = response;
data.items.forEach((item) => {
  const title = (`${item.snippet.title}`)
  console.log(title)//logs every result
  fs.writeFileSync('filePath', title)//logs only the last string
})
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you keep overwriting the file, so only the last string is in the file. You need to use `appendFile`, rather than `writeFile`, which overwrites the previous data.

```
 google.youtube('v3').videos.list({
  key: youtubeKey,
  part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
  id: 'Ks-_Mh1QhMc,c0KYU2j0TM4,eIho2S0ZahI',
}).then((response) => {
const {
  data
} = response;
data.items.forEach((item) => {
  const title = (`${item.snippet.title}`)
  fs.appendFileSync('filePath', title)//logs all strings
})
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: yes, that was the problem, Thanks will accept the answer when the timer is done.@r3fl3ct